# Unable to update fonts on html using vite and custom local fonts

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts, vite

I using Vite as a builder in my ReactJS project and trying to add custom fonts to my website. However, I do not see any change in the browser view after adding the required code.

Here's my code:

```css
/* fonts.scss */
@font-face {
    font-family: 'sohne';
    src: url('../../fonts/sohne/Sohne-Extraleicht.otf') format('otf');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: normal;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: 'sohne';
    src: url('../../fonts/sohne/Sohne-ExtraleichtKursiv.otf') format('otf');
    font-weight: 200;
    font-style: italic;
}

/* ...and a few other styles */
```

I have included this in vite.config.js and used the [vite-plugin-fonts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vite-plugin-fonts)

```js
import ViteFonts from 'vite-plugin-fonts';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        ViteFonts({
            custom: {
                families: {
                    'sohne': './src/assets/fonts/sohne/Sohne*.otf'
                }
            }
        })
    ]
})
```

this is how I am using it in my CSS styling:

```css
.some-class {
  font-family: 'sohne';
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked for me to write a different path (only `url('/fonts/...`) for fonts inside the `public`-folder:

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 300;
  src: url('/fonts/roboto-300.woff2') format('woff2'),
    url('/fonts/roboto-300.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/roboto-300.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```